# Memcpy with unsigned short *

Tags: c

I have my loop

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        {
           pDest[i] = pSource[i]; // Both are unsigned short *
        }
}
```

I copy the content of pSource in pDest and that's works.
pDest and pSource are both unsigned short *.
I had improve this for loop so i user omp parallel.

```
#pragma omp parallel for shared(pDest, srcBuffer)
```

I try to use another way with memcpy and I have wrong value into my pDest

```
memcpy(pDest, srcBuffer, sizeof(unsigned short)); // I copy srcBuffer into pDest and the size of the bytes are unsigned short because pDest and srcBuffer are unsigned short *
```

My first value of pDest are:
83-47039-0
And it should be:
83-86-77

My first value is correct, so maybe the last parameter of memcpy is wrong ?
I try to give my size instead of sizeof(unsigned short)

```
memcpy(pDest, srcBuffer, size);
```

And that's work !! but sometimes all my value are equal to 0-0-0

I have no idea why my value are sometimes bad initizialed.

Comment: I would use `size * sizeof *pDest` for the size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `memcpy` to know how much data to copy, you need to specify the number of elements times the size of each element:

```
memcpy(pDest, srcBuffer, size * sizeof(unsigned short));
```